# Bing QR Scan on Windows Phone 8 with custom protocol

Tags: windows-phone-8, qr-code, bing

I have a WP 8 app which is registered to open via a custom protocol (i.e. foo:// ) and this works when launched via Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync.

However when Bing vision on WP 8 sees a QR code with foo://bar it doesn't launch my app and just displays "Message:foo:bar".

How can I get Bing Vision to launch my app when scanning the QR code?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the custom protocol to work with bing vision but http:// and a custom file exstention did work. 
I created a url http://example.com/foo.bar which I encoded in a QR. 
Bing vision passes this to IE which then asks if it should open the .bar file in my app.

This solution isn't as clean but it works.

Windows Phone file associations are documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx